# Unable to set state in a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

So I was trying to build a server side pagination that works like a static one and I'm almost there, But I've encountered some issues which I cannot seem to solve.

This is what my code looks like

```
const LiveIndex = (props) => {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const startLoading = () => setLoading(true);
  const stopLoading = () => setLoading(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    //After the component is mounted set router event handlers

    Router.events.on("routeChangeStart", startLoading);
    Router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", stopLoading);

    return () => {
      Router.events.off("routeChangeStart", startLoading);
      Router.events.off("routeChangeComplete", stopLoading);
    };
  }, []);

  const paginationHandler = (page) => {
    const currentPath = props.router.pathname;
    const currentQuery = props.router.query;
    currentQuery.page = currentPage + 1;

    props.router.push({
      pathname: currentPath,
      query: currentQuery,
    });
    setCurrentPage(currentQuery.page);
  };

  const backToLastPage = (page) => {
    const currentPath = props.router.pathname;
    const currentQuery = props.router.query;

    currentQuery.page = currentPage - 1;
    setCurrentPage(currentQuery.page); // THE code that breaks my code.

    props.router.push({
      pathname: currentPathh,
      query: currentQueryy,
    });
  };

  let content;
  if (isLoading) {
    content = (
      <div>
        <h2 class="loading-text">loading.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    //Generating posts list

    content = (
      <div className="container">
        <h2> Live Games - </h2>

        <div className="columns is-multiline">
          <p>{props.games.name}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className={"container-md"}>
        <div>{content}</div>

        {props.games.length ? (
          <a onClick={() => paginationHandler(currentPage)}> moore </a>
        ) : (
          backToLastPage(currentPage)
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {
  const page = query.page || 1; //if page empty we request the first page
  const response = await fetch(
    `exampleapi.com?sort=&page=${page}&per_page=10&token`
  );

  const data = await response.json();
  return {
    props: {
      games: data,
    },
  };
}

export default withRouter(LiveIndex);
```

The issue is my `backToLastPage` does the job well but I'm unable to use `setCurrentPage()` in that function, Every time I use that I get the following error

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop
```

How can I possibly update the value of my currentPage state in the `backToLast` function

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `backToLastPage` directly in JSX which will be re-rendered/re-called every time. And `setCurrentPage` (with `useState`) triggers re-rendering for state changes in `backToLastPage`.

You can imagine that every time the state changes, your component gets rendered and it will set states again that make infinite renderings for the component.

You can use `useEffect` to handle `props.games` changes. That will help you to trigger `backToLastPage` only once whenever `props.games` get changed.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
   if(!props.games || !props.games.length) {
      backToLastPage(currentPage)
   }
},[props.games])
```

Full modification can be

```
const LiveIndex = (props) => {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const startLoading = () => setLoading(true);
  const stopLoading = () => setLoading(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    //After the component is mounted set router event handlers

    Router.events.on("routeChangeStart", startLoading);
    Router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", stopLoading);

    return () => {
      Router.events.off("routeChangeStart", startLoading);
      Router.events.off("routeChangeComplete", stopLoading);
    };
  }, []);

  //The main change is here
  //It will be triggered whenever `props.games` gets updated
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if(!props.games || !props.games.length) {
      backToLastPage(currentPage)
    }
  },[props.games])

  const paginationHandler = (page) => {
    const currentPath = props.router.pathname;
    const currentQuery = props.router.query;
    currentQuery.page = currentPage + 1;

    props.router.push({
      pathname: currentPath,
      query: currentQuery,
    });
    setCurrentPage(currentQuery.page);
  };

  const backToLastPage = (page) => {
    const currentPath = props.router.pathname;
    const currentQuery = props.router.query;

    currentQuery.page = currentPage - 1;
    setCurrentPage(currentQuery.page); // THE code that breaks my code.

    props.router.push({
      pathname: currentPathh,
      query: currentQueryy,
    });
  };

  let content;
  if (isLoading) {
    content = (
      <div>
        <h2 class="loading-text">loading.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    //Generating posts list

    content = (
      <div className="container">
        <h2> Live Games - </h2>

        <div className="columns is-multiline">
          <p>{props.games.name}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className={"container-md"}>
        <div>{content}</div>

        {props.games.length && (
          <a onClick={() => paginationHandler(currentPage)}> moore </a>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {
  const page = query.page || 1; //if page empty we request the first page
  const response = await fetch(
    `exampleapi.com?sort=&page=${page}&per_page=10&token`
  );

  const data = await response.json();
  return {
    props: {
      games: data,
    },
  };
}

export default withRouter(LiveIndex);
```

Comment: Hey, I noticed a slight issue due to using useEffect, So lets say for example there's a page on which the `props.games` is really empty, then on load the state value of `currentPage` just starts going random as the `backToLastPage` function gets fired, I think the only way to prevent this from happening is to not use the `useEffect` hook right?

Comment: Hmm I thought that was your intention according to your logic in your question. Could you elaborate more which situation you trigger `backToLastPage` and which situation you don't? @KentrellJr

Comment: So for example suppose on page load the value of `{props.games}` is empty, If this happens the code just breaks down and my state value of `currentPage` keeps reducing due to the `backToLastPage` function being invoked constantly, for this situation I wouldn't like the function to be triggered

Comment: On page load, it will fetch `props.games` on the server which does not trigger `useEffect`. When it comes to the client-side, one of the possible cases is your API returns no games on the server-side. In my humble opinion, you should think about how to use `backToLastPage` when you don't have game data in your logic @KentrellJr